# Проблема с настройкой сканера

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Модель: Epson PErfection V30 
Драйвера скачивал с офф. сайта и запускал установку в соответствии с их инструкцией (автоматическая установка "./install.sh"). Перезагрузка компа и сканера ничем не помогли и смена портов тоже. Приложение просит поставить дрова на сканер, а вроде как ставил последнюю версию. Что делать? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Дайте название приложения, которое у вас просит дрова (каламбур но как есть...)

Comment: А `sane` не видит железку?

Comment: Sane сканер видит, но вот программы ругаются. @donRumata

Comment: Как я понял, это стандартная программа "Простое сканирование". @Hellseher